# Backbone Redirect from before route function

Tags: jquery, redirect, backbone.js

I have a function that runs before every route in a backbone app

```
route: function(route, name, callback) {
        var router = this;
        if (!callback) callback = this[name];

        var beforeRoute = function() {
            var location = Backbone.history.fragment;
            var status = this.authorize();

            if(location =="" && status['logged_in'] == true){
                router.navigate("stream", {trigger: true});
            } else if(location !="" && status['logged_in'] == false){
                router.navigate("login", {trigger: true});
            }

            callback.apply(router, arguments);
        };
        return Backbone.Router.prototype.route.call(this, route, name, beforeRoute);
},
```

This is in my router and essentially it checks if the user is logged in or not on every call. My issue is the

```
  router.navigate("stream", {trigger: true});
```

doesn't fire as expected (should redirect to the stream route). I've tried this.navigate and attempted to set route = "stream" but none redirect as expected - except for reassigning window.location which causes the page to reload, not ideal for the app.

Any advice on how to reroute from within this beforeRoute function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap that last bit in an else block

```
} else {
    callback.apply(router, arguments);
}
```